# Google Maps Android API how to check if quota limit is reached?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I've been experimenting a bit with the Google Maps Android API and was wondering if there is a way to detect if your quota limit (2500 a day) is reached to be able to show a message based on that (in Java using Android Studio).

I've been searching and could only find comments concerning the Google Maps API using javascript but nothing about the Android API. I've also tried finding something in the documentation but maybe I didn't search correctly?
Help would be appreciated.

I'm using Google Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no limits on Google Maps Android API.

The following APIs do not have usage limits:

```
Google Maps Android API
Google Maps SDK for iOS
Google Maps Embed API
```

Usage limits apply to the following Maps APIs.

```
Google Maps JavaScript API
Google Static Maps API
Google Street View Image API
Google Maps Directions API
Google Maps Distance Matrix API
Google Maps Elevation API
Google Maps Geocoding API
Google Maps Geolocation API
Google Maps Roads API
Google Maps Time Zone API
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I thought I had seen a 2500 mentioned for Google Maps Android API somewhere. I don't know where I saw that. My mistake.

Comment: You are welcome. Please upvote my answer too if it was helpful. Actually Google Maps Web service APIs have a limit of 2500 requests in a day

Comment: I upvoted, but it doesn't show up since I'm too new to stackoverflow. I hope it still does something for you!

Comment: No problem! Thanks